# Proof of Fermat's theorem on extremum of functions

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, proof-verification

Here's the statement of Fermat : "Let $f :\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ (generally $f$ is defined on an open set), if $f$ is differentiable at $c \in \mathbb{R}$ and has a local extremum at this point then $f'(c)=0$".

Here's my proof : Suppose that $f$ has a local extremum at the point $c$ (w.l.o.g, we can consider that it is a maximum) :

There is an $\eta>0$ such that $\forall \ x \in ]c-\eta, c+\eta[$, $f(x)\le f(c)$.

So $\forall \ x \in ]c-\eta, c+\eta[$, $f(x)-f(c) \le 0$.

Then we have :

$\frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c} \le 0$ if $x-c>0$ and $\frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c} \ge 0$ if $x-c>0$

But we know that $f$ is differentiable at $c$, so we can write that : $\lim \limits_\underset{x\ne c}{x\to c} \frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c}=f'(c)$.

Passing to the limits we have : $\lim \limits_\underset{x>c}{{x\to c}} \frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c}\le 0 \le \lim\limits_\underset{x<c}{{x\to c}} \frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c}$ $\Leftrightarrow$ $f'(c)\le 0 \le f'(c)$

Hence, $f'(c)=0$.

Is it a correct proof ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Footnote: Fermat was an enormously talented person, to see such in a context that had no vocabulary for any such thing. The sense of "calculus" then was... null.. so/and the context was "vacuum". Crazy.

Comment: It's remarkable that Fermat died just a few months before Newton began to develope his differential calculus.

Comment: @paulgarrett Considering that Fermat had none of these notions, whatever he actually proved is going to look nothing like this. Indeed, the first source I can find that even mentions his original proof shows he was considering polynomials and using small displacements. So he's approximating tangents by secants and then pretending the points become the same. It's around the time when algebra and geometry were being used in each other's areas, but before anyone had worked out what Descartes was on about.

Comment: The general idea is right. Some rewriting would be useful. The line that starts with "First if $x=c$" should be deleted. And at the end there should be some explanation of why the derivative, if it exists, must be $0$. (The limit from the right is $\le 0$, the limit from the left is $\ge 0$.)

Comment: @AndréNicolas Thank you for checkin ! Edit made !

Comment: @Maman: In my opinion you use too many symbols and too few words.  In particular, the sentence towards the end that starts with "Then:" is unnecessarily convoluted. So is the sentence towards the beginning that  starts with "Let $\eta\gt 0$".

Comment: As Watt ends: "no symbols where none intended".

Comment: Fermat did far more than anything about  Differential calculus. History testifies that (Fermat  actually appears as a precursor of calculus)

Comment: Please read your sentence $\exists\eta \dots$. Ambiguous, or worse. Try not to use the double implication. You want to say that there is an $\eta\gt 0$ such that $f(x)\le f(c)$ for all $x$ in that interval. So $f(x)-f(c)\le 0$ in that interval.

Comment: @AndréNicolas I understood that it was too formal, now I find that the proof is clearer.

Comment: Sorry to nag endlessly. Your "Passing to the limits" sentence towards the end is insufficiently clear. You know what's happening. So it is very much worthwhile to communicate it.